# Export some specific pages from data driven pages to pdf file by python

Tags: python, data, export, arcpy, data-driven-pages

I need to export pages 14, 13, 23 and 24 of 26 pages of data driven pages to pdf file by python and then add the pdf file to the final pdf file by arcpy (python), any help please?

Comment: This blog post on [**Combining Data Driven Pages with Python and arcpy.mapping**](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2010/12/14/combining-data-driven-pages-with-python-and-arcpy-mapping/) is a good starting point but you may want to just get the very basics working and then, if you get stuck, edit your question to post your code so far.

Answer (score 2):

From the [online help for data driven pages and ExportToPDF](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00s300000030000000), it looks like you want to identify

- `page_range_type = 'RANGE'`
- `page_range_string = '14, 13, 23, 24, 26'`